# How to return function call with Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Maybe i have a stoopid question, but i want to return function call with promise .then and with async function, to later use this on express.js

```
function search (opts) {
 //const url
 //const callback

return request(url, callback)
.then(res => {
  const promisesAccounts = res.accounts.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));
  const promisesKeyword = res.keyword.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));

  const hello = async () => {

  const obj = {};

  const promiseA = await Promise.all(promisesAccounts);
  const promiseB = await Promise.all(promisesKeyword);
  obj.accounts = promiseA;
  obj.keywords = promiseB;
  console.log(obj);
}
hello()
})
}
```

Maybe somehow i can return obj to later use it on express app like this :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   search()
   .then (result => res.json(result))  //hello async obj result  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `return` your function like this

```
function search (opts) {
  //const url
  //const callback

  return request(url, callback)
    .then(res => {
      const promisesAccounts = res.accounts.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));
      const promisesKeyword = res.keyword.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));

      const hello = async () => {
        const obj = {};
        const promiseA = await Promise.all(promisesAccounts);
        const promiseB = await Promise.all(promisesKeyword);
        obj.accounts = promiseA;
        obj.keywords = promiseB;
        console.log(obj);
      }
      return hello;
    })
}
```

To use this you can then

```
request
  .then(async myFunc => {
     const value = await muFunc(parameter_here)
  })
```

Comment: myFunc thats reference to hello func ?

Comment: @AlbertJovinskyi Yes! It refers to the hello func. But if you want just the computed value of the function Sergii's answer is what you should look up to

Comment: yes thank you i'll gonna try with your variant, its more intresting)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
function search (opts) {

  return request(url, callback)
    .then(res => {
      const promisesAccounts = res.accounts.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));
      const promisesKeyword = res.keyword.map( el => request(el, callbackPage));

      const hello = async () => {

        const obj = {};

        const promiseA = await Promise.all(promisesAccounts);
        const promiseB = await Promise.all(promisesKeyword);
        obj.accounts = promiseA;
        obj.keywords = promiseB;
        console.log(obj);
        return obj;
      }
      return hello()
  })
}
```